# load directly an audio file with librosa in dB

Tags: audio, decibel, librosa

Is there a way to directly load an audio file with librosa in dB instead of amplitude as obtained by:

```
y, sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

`librosa` as mentioned in [this paper](http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/scipy2015/pdfs/brian_mcfee.pdf), pulls audio file as one dimensional `numpy array`.

from the documentation:

> An audio signal is represented as a one-dimensional numpy array, denoted as
>   y throughout `librosa`. Typically the signal y is accompanied by the sampling rate (denoted sr ) which denotes the frequency (in Hz) at which values of y
>   are sampled.

From the code:

```
>>> type(y)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> y
array([-0.00265948, -0.0045677 , -0.00412048, ..., -0.00179085,
       -0.00228079, -0.00238096], dtype=float32)
>>>
```

`librosa` makes use of  The  array elements of `y` and sampling rate for its calculations and representation.

You may need to elaborate as to **"load directly an audio file with `librosa` in dB"** and it's intended purpose.

Comment: thanks for your response: the one-dimensional numpy array y represents the audio amplitude for each sample point?

Comment: Yes, `numpy` array y represents audio amplitude of each sample point.

Comment: How can I trasfrom the amplitude of each sample point of 1d array (from librosa) to a dB value? Thanks.